# How do I UPDATE with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to `SET` the price of `SOFTWARE` to some other value depending on two conditions:

1. `SOFTWARE` that have a name that starts with M.
2. `SOFTWARE` that are installed in the `INSTALLER` table

Code:

```sql
SELECT N_SOF,NAMESOF FROM SOFTWARE;

      N_SOF NAMESOF
---------- -------------------------
        64 WINDOWS
        70 WINDOWS
        71 MAC
        72 MAC
        73 MAC

SELECT N_INS,N_SOF FROM INSTALLER;

    N_INS       N_SOF
---------- ----------
         3         71
         3         72
        12         73
```

I tried this, in SQL*PLUS (ORACLE), but it didn't work.

```sql
SQL> UPDATE SOFTWARE
  2  SET PRICE= PRICE+100
  3  INNER JOIN INSTALLER I ON I.NLOG=SOFTWARE.N_SOF
  4  WHERE SOFTWARE.NAMESOF='M%' AND I.N_INS=3;
```

I got this error message

```sql
INNER JOIN INSTALLER I ON I.NLOG=LOGICIEL.NLOG
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: Use MERGE instead of UPDATE, or use WHERE EXISTS() instead of the join.

Comment: @MatBailie We didn't study that command in my course. Is there some other way?

Comment: You `INSTALLER` table does not have an `NLOG` column and there are no `NAMESOF` values that equal `M%` (you probably meant to use `LIKE` rather than equals for that latter issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE SOFTWARE
SET PRICE= PRICE+100
WHERE
  SOFTWARE.NAMESOF LIKE 'M%' 
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM INSTALLER I
     WHERE I.NLOG=SOFTWARE.N_SOF
       AND I.N_INS=3
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UPDATE` with an `EXISTS` clause:

```sql
UPDATE SOFTWARE s
  SET PRICE= PRICE+100
WHERE NAMESOF LIKE 'M%'
AND   EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM   INSTALLER i
             WHERE  i.N_SOF=s.N_SOF
             AND    i.N_INS=3);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE software (N_SOF, NAMESOF, price) AS
SELECT 64, 'WINDOWS', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 70, 'WINDOWS', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 71, 'MAC',     0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 72, 'MAC',     0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73, 'MAC',     0 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE INSTALLER (N_INS, N_SOF) AS
SELECT  3, 71 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 72 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 73 FROM DUAL;
```

After the update then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM software
```

Outputs:

> | N_SOF | NAMESOF | PRICE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 64 | WINDOWS | 0 |
> | 70 | WINDOWS | 0 |
> | 71 | MAC | 100 |
> | 72 | MAC | 100 |
> | 73 | MAC | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c9f9df52df891a73235b26acb1a7a000)*